# return value list in go programing

Tags: go

[image]

I am new to coding, can someone advise why "x" in present in the 2nd circle， Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The first `func (int) int` is a data type that is a function that takes an integer, and returns an integer.

The second

```
return func (x int) int {
...
}
```

is a function that takes an integer, and returns an integer, and the function definition itself uses `x` as the name of the input argument.

If the function definition did not use the `x` at all, it could have used:

```
return func (int) int {
...
}
```